# Exception from WebAuthn Authentication API with Yubikey

Tags: javascript, webauthn, yubico

I'm working on adding WebAuthn support to a newly-minted web site and am running into a problem during the navigator.credentials.get() call. The client is Firefox 85.0 on Fedora 33. In case it matters, the server is Apache httpd on Fedora 33. The token is either a Yubikey 4 or a Yubikey 5NFC (the results are the same). This is the function making the API call. Obviously the credential IDs hard-coded here are for testing, not part of the final product:

```
function handleUserAuthenticationResponse(r) {
  var cid1 = {type: "public-key", id: base64ToArrayBuffer("gL0Ig10uA2tn8L0kn2L9FoGqIPSrqvc1lLBwgQhcVDa200b1P94kPv94T6O1bDZyYRrfLbTrLRsubDxuYUxHCg==")};
  var cid2 = {type: "public-key", id: base64ToArrayBuffer("tjW1RPqtAJm69I/qeV7eRFJx6h87J3NPeJ/hhbkjttcCc2BWHQ2v2nueoKBSGabw1eYsT8S+lhJv1l1mYWX+Uw==")};
  var options = {
    rpID: "http://localhost",
    challenge: base64ToArrayBuffer(r.challenge),
    allowCredentials: [cid1,cid2],
    timeout: 60000
  };

  if (!window.PublicKeyCredential) {
    throw new Error("Unable to access credentials interface");
  }
  navigator.credentials.get({"publicKey":options})
    .then(assertion => handleTokenAssertion(assertion))
    .catch(e => {console.log("Error fetching token assertion:",e);});
}
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
function handleTokenAssertion(a) {
  alert("Got an assertion!");
}
```

Everything seems to work, the Yubikey LED blinks, I press the touchpad, but then I get back an exception:

```
Error fetching token assertion: DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

This seems to be a bit of a Firefox catch-all. It could indicate that the token doesn't match one of the allowedCredentials[], or perhaps other things. It's hard to tell. The FIDO2 credential on the Yubikey was created with fido2-cred(1) tool packaged with the libfido2 source. In this case the credentialId is from the `fido2-cred -M` output:

```
CuCEGL10uPhBmNCY4NsGaAz0gir/68UMGFQn0pfb6tc=
http://localhost
fido-u2f
WMSGBbi6CMINQvnkVRUYcYltDg3pgFlihvtzbRHuwBPipEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgL0Ig10uA2tn8L0kn2L9FoGqIPSrqvc1lLBwgQhcVDa200b1P94kPv94T6O1bDZyYRrfLbTrLRsubDxuYUxHCqUBAgMmIAEhWCA5itRRCBO0lnsztvPvI1waVZLBCZ1XMJjOvlN2oZmBCyJYILFaRjThs5Paj1sOp81iID1LpUBYHJhp4dizC0eI/RrE
gL0Ig10uA2tn8L0kn2L9FoGqIPSrqvc1lLBwgQhcVDa200b1P94kPv94T6O1bDZyYRrfLbTrLRsubDxuYUxHCg==
MEQCIFfs8PagKhNnDgzxfurVzdkTDVTT6ixKk0ak/2qrbSPUAiAf64w390rX1cyY58JgSC/Ac97w6TLcYKuqxOSn5lxV0g==
<long assertion certificate>
```

You can see the credentialId on line 5, and that it matches `cid1` in the Javascript function. Furthermore, if I request an assertion from the token using this credentialId and all else identical (except the challenge) with `fido2-assert -G`, everything works fine: I get the assertion and it verifies correctly using `fido2-assert -V`.

Without a more meaningful diagnostic it's hard to know what to try, so I thought I would ask here and see if anyone has any hints. Perhaps I've made some basic error with either Javascript or the credentials API?

Thanks!

UPDATE: One possibility I thought might be worth trying was removing the scheme from the RP ID but that made no difference.

UPDATE: Looking at the firefox source code, the error is apparently NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_STATE_ERR, which covers several different situations but in this case is most likely a translation of U2F_ERROR_INVALID_STATE (in dom/webauthn/U2FHIDTokenManager.h). U2F_ERROR_INVALID_STATE, in turn, is defined in third_party/rust/authenticator/src/u2fhid-capi.h as a simple numerical value (3), with no indication of where the value came from. Perhaps it's defined by the underlying HID driver for the Yubikey, but it's not clear what driver that corresponds to. The hunt continues...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was indeed the format of the relying party ID. Based on example code from the net (which may have worked with other browsers or versions of the code?), I initially used the full scheme://domain format for the rpID (so in my code above, `http://localhost`), but it turns out that what's needed is just the domain (`localhost`). Modifying the rpID in this way allows the assertion process to succeed.

Initially I thought this did not work, but it turned out that I'd simply forgotten to commit the change. Having belatedly done that, it works.